# How to test nested component's method in lifecycle with enzyme / jest?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

In these lifecycles (componentDidMount & ComponentDidUpdate), I want to see if  `myMethod` is being called. This function creates a HOC, decorates it with another HOC (WithFeature - not detailed here - that uses the redux store);

**WithMyMethod.js**

```
export default page => WrappedComponent => {
  class WithMyMethod extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      if (this.props.isFeatureEnabled) {
        this.myMethod();
      }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.isFeatureEnabled && page === 'Home') {
        this.myMethod();
      }
    }

    myMethod() {
    // code
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props)} />;
    }
  }

  return WithFeature('featureName')(WithMyMethod);
};
```

**__tests__/WithMyMethod**

In my tests, I'm using `mount`from enzyme to use the lifecycles.

```
const TestComponent = () => null;
const WithMyMethodComponent = withMyMethod('Home')(TestComponent);

describe('withMyMethod', () => {
  test('when feature is enabled', () => {

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={getContext(stateWithFeatureEnabled)}>
        <WithMyMethodComponent />
      </Provider>,
    );

    // from here, how can I spy on 'myMethod' to check if it was invoked or not ?
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't spy on myMethod, because it's part of the thing you're trying to test. Test what it *does*, not how it's implemented.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is right, Life cycle methods and setState etc are the implementation details. We should not test the implementation details. We should be testing the methods containing business logics  or the UI (user interactions).